# Customers that stopped ordering monthly-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write an SQL query that shows STORES that stopped ordering in a month. That would be STORES that have orders the month before but no orders that month. For example STORES that have orders in January but do Not have orders in Febuary  (these would be the STORES that  stopped ordering for Febuary). I want to do this for every month (grouped) for a given date range - @datefrom-@dateto

I have one table with an INVOICE#,STORE# and a DATE column

I guess distinct STORE would be in there somewhere.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Result- January  10 Febuary 14 march 7 April etc..  I have one table with an INVOICE#,STORE# and a DATE column

Comment: Kindly edit your question and post the sample data and expected result.

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you, would you mind marking it as an answer to give closure to your question? Thank you, @Chobes

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, break them into two select statements and left outer join them.

```
select table1.stores from (select * from table where date = 'January') as table1 
left outer join (select * from table where date = 'Feburary') as table2 
on table1.invoice= table2.invoice
```

this will return the unique results in January that does not match the results from February

ps. that was not an exact sql statement, just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I have an example that might be close to what you desire. You may have to tweak it to your convenience and desired performance - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/231c4/15

```
create table test (
  invoice int identity,
  store int,
  dt date
);

-- let's add some data to show that
-- store 1 ordered in Jan, Feb and Mar
-- store 2 ordered in Jan (missed Feb and Mar)
-- store 3 ordered in Jan and Mar (missed Feb)
insert into test (store, dt) values 
(1, '2015-01-01'),(1, '2015-02-01'),(1, '2015-03-01'),
(2, '2015-01-01'),
(3, '2015-01-01'),                  (3, '2015-03-01');

Query
-----
with 
months as (select distinct year(dt) as yr, month(dt) as mth from test),
stores as (select distinct store from test),
months_stores as (select * from months cross join stores)

select * 
from months_stores ms
left join test t
  on t.store = ms.store
  and year(t.dt) = ms.yr
  and month(t.dt) = ms.mth
where 
  (ms.yr = 2015 and ms.mth between 1 and 3)
  and t.invoice is null

Result:
yr     mth     store   ...other columns
2015   2       2
2015   2       3
2015   3       2

The results show us that store 2 missed orders in months Feb and Mar
and store 3 missed an order in Feb
```